# Analytical geometry proof of the invariance of cross ratio under a projective transformation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, ratio

I was reading about the cross ratio and wanted to go through its proof but I was not able to find appropriate proofs on internet and most proofs required knowledge of abstract algebra and determinants.

Please show a proof using simple analytical geometry, if possible.

Comment: I it more general to consider the cross ratio of a **pencil of four lines** and use its expression with sines, like in https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Cross-Ratio.shtml

Comment: @Jean Marie thank's I have understood